# Issue while Installing calyptia-fluentd on RHEL7

Tags: ruby, rubygems, redhat, fluentd

I'm trying to install RPM Package on the RHEL7 following the installation steps guided on this page:

I was able to install the td-agent successfully, launched the daemon, and tested it by sending sample logs via HTTP. As the next step, I tried to install "calyptia-fluentd" but while installing for Redhat using the curl command shown below:

curl -L https://calyptia-fluentd.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/calyptia-fluentd-1-redhat.sh | sh

It throws an error saying "Error: Package: calyptia-fluentd-yum-release-2021.5.1-release.noarch (/calyptia-fluentd-yum-release-2021.5.1-release.noarch)
Requires: dnf-command(config-manager)"

I have also tried to manually run the script by specifying the RedHat version but no luck. DNF-command is for RHEL 8 but not sure why it's throwing up when trying to install calyptia-fluentd on RHEL 7.

Can someone help me understand on how to resolve the issue and complete the installation?

For ref, Please find the attached screenshot.
https://docs.fluentd.org/installation/install-by-rpm#using-to-install-calyptia-fluentd

[image]

As alternative, I tried to install Ruby INterpreter using Snap by following the instructuon shown below:

https://snapcraft.io/install/ruby/rhel

Additionally, I'm trying to install ruby-dev package via package manager to build native extenstion but no luck  and it dependent on the gem installation shown in the next steps.

Also, I tried to install using gen command "**gem install fluentd --no-doc** but its throwing an error as shown below:

[image]

Comment: For the first error, did you try to install `dnf`? Most probably, the command would be `sudo yum update -y && sudo yum install -y dnf`. And, then rerun the script. As for the second error, to build native extensions, the package `ruby-devel` is missing and needs to be installed first.

Comment: Hi Azeem, I have tried this method and when I try to install dnf, it says "No Package dnf available". Similar to dnf, yum install ruby-devel says "No package ruby-devel available".  Any idea about installing ruby-devel package on RHEL 7.9?

Comment: Did you update `sudo yum update` before running `sudo yum install -y dnf`?

Comment: You can search for `dnf` package also i.e. `yum search dnf`. BTW, this question is best suited for https://serverfault.com/. It'll get better responses there. You might want to migrate it to https://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure your distribution is redhat(`cat /etc/system-release-cpe` or `cat /etc/os-release`) and the version is 7, try the following.

```
curl --output /tmp/calyptia-fluentd-yum-release-2021.5.1-release.noarch.rpm https://calyptia-fluentd.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/1/redhat/7/calyptia-fluentd-yum-release-2021.5.1-release.noarch.rpm
yum install -y /tmp/calyptia-fluentd-yum-release-2021.5.1-release.noarch.rpm
yum install -y calyptia-fluentd 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the flags for GCC are wrong. Those flags are not compatible with older versions of Ruby that the package includes. Removing the flags mentioned in the error from /opt/calyptia-fluentd/lib/ruby/3.0.0/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb should allow you to continue to build.